# looping in javascript - callback happening before first loop is fully over

Tags: node.js, loops, callback

need some help in correcting a loop closure in javascript.

**Required flow**: MasterGet function is run, data is fetched from a mysql table, for each record fetched a set of 'rules' is run.

**Issue faced**: if there are two records fetched, while 'rules' are being run for record 1, the record 2 'rules' also get triggered.  Need to modify code such at record 2 is checked only after the 'rules' action is completed for record 1.

```
function MasterGet() {
    var countCheckRule = 0;
    connection.query(
    'SELECT * FROM MASTER',
    function selectCb(error, rows, fields) {
        if (error) {
          console.log('Log 045 - GetData Error: ' + error.message);
          return;
        }
            
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            console.log(+ rows[i].INDEX1);
            var firstResult = rows[i];
            rules.checRules(firstResult, myhttp, function (rules_res) {
            firstResult.rules = rules_res;
                })
        }
    });            
    countCheckRule++;
    setTimeout(funcL, 4000);
};
 


Any guidance will help.  Thanks
```

**Added to the issue:**
The rules.checrules coding is as below:

```
exports.checRules = function (A, myhttp, _callback) {
var objrules = { 'rule12': false };
    
function rule11() {
        if (A.NQ > 0 && A.PSQ > 0) {
            objrules.rule11 = true;
            if (config.execute) {
                modifyOrder('S', 'A.BQ', A.TS);
                }
        } else {
            objrules.rule11 = false;
            
        }
    }

    rule11(); 

    _callback(objrules);
}
```

So in the loop for 1st record, it checks rule11, and if rule11 is true then it has to execute 'modifyOrder' with the given variables, after 'modifyOrder' is completed, then go back to the loop and check for the 2nd record.  If Rule11 is false for the 1st record, then it should automatically go back to the loop and check for the 2nd record.

Currently with the given changes, **2nd record check gets triggered before 'modifyOrder' is complete**.  Maybe the issue is that the code does not wait for the callback from 'modifyOrder'?  Is that the issue? How can I make the code wait till 'modifyOrder' is complete if started.

Answer (score 0):

This code may solve your problem.
This kind of problem accord bez of async nature of js.

```
function asyncLoop(i, rows, cb) {
if (i < rows.length) {
    rules.checRules(rows[i], myhttp, function (rules_res) {
        console.log(rules_res);
        asyncLoop(i + 1, rows, cb);
        //your code
    });
   } else {
    cb();
  }
}

function MasterGet() {
connection.query(
    'SELECT * FROM MASTER',
    function selectCb(error, rows, fields) {
        if (error) {
            console.log('Log 045 - GetData Error: ' + error.message);
            return;
        }
        asyncLoop(0, rows, () => {
            //after async loop complete...
        });
    });
 countCheckRule++;
 setTimeout(funcL, 4000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs.  I am still not able to get it to work.  I have added a few more details in my original post to try and explain the problem better.  Hope you can help.

Comment: I need moor information :-( , But if modifyOrder is async (took some time to exe) you can use async await. without full conde review, I cant help u.